# Is it ok to ask your fans to share your page with their friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

Facebook now allows *non-admins* to invite their friends to like a page, if some of your friends already like that page.

[This article](http://www.marketinggum.com/what-you-cannot-do-on-facebook-page-admins-read-these-rules/) says that we shouldn't ask page fans to "invite their friends to like a page", but I couldn't find anything about it in the [Facebook Pages terms.](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php)

Is it ok to ask page fans to share the page with their friends? (or invite their friends to like it)

Comment: What do you mean by illegal? Like will you be prosecuted to the fullest extent of the law, or does Facebook frown upon it?

Comment: Like Facebook removing our page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with your opening statement.  As written in [Facebook's official Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/morelikes), only Page admins can formally "invite" friends to a Page.  Non-admins can *share* the page with others, but not formally *invite*.

The portion of the article that you are quoting is referring to the prohibition against using Facebook features and functionality specifically when running (or promoting) a ***promotion***.

As part of one's day-to-day engagement with fans, it is perfectly acceptable to include "calls-to-action" such as "invite your friends", ... etc.

BTW: not everything written in this article is (currently) correct.  For example, many of the restrictions regarding what can or cannot appear in the Cover photo [have been relaxed](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/03/20/facebook-changes-cover-photo-policy-20-text-rule-in-effect-but-content-less-regulated/).  The main restriction that remains is the "20% text rule".

Comment: It seems it's a new feature, if some of your friends already liked a page, Facebook allows you to *invite* your other friends to like it too, you can find its link under the list of your friends which liked a page.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I now see it.  However, it is bit misleading! Facebook allows me to "**Share** this Page with more friends", but what gets sent out is indeed an invitation ("<NAME> has **invited** you to like <FAN PAGE>").